# AutoHotKey key-pressing script for a game

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I have a little trouble with game Resident Evil 6 and need help.

Well, I want that my script press buttons <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>O</kbd> at the same time whenever I press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
I tried to write such a script and the script works in Windows perfectly, but it doesn't work in the game.

**Script:**

```
tab::
Send, l
Send, o
```

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the [SendPlay](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#games) functionality.

> Some games use DirectInput exclusively. As a side-effect, they might ignore all simulated keystrokes and mouse clicks

Here is an example:

```
Tab::
    SendPlay, {l down}{l up}{o down}{o up}
return
```

If that doesn't work, then take a look at the link above and try one of the other solutions.

Comment: Did it help? if so, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/229213), so this topic can be closed.